# Why is the $\text{End}_A(M)$-module $\text{Hom}_A(N,M)$ finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be an Artin algebra and let $M,N$ be some finitely generated modules in mod(A).

Why is then the $\text{End}_A(M)$-module $\text{Hom}_A(N,M)$ finitely generated?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This isn't true in general: Take $A=M$ a finite field and let $N$ be infinite. Then $End_A(M)=A$ is finite and $Hom_A(N,M)$ can't be a finitely generated module since it's infinite.

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\H{\operatorname{Hom}}$There is an epimorphism $A^n\to N$, which implies a monomorphism of $B$-modules $\H_A(N,M)\to\H_A(A^n,M)$, where $B=\operatorname{End}_A(M)$. Since $\H_A(A^n,M)\cong M^n$ as $B$-modules, it's sufficient to prove that $M$ has finite length as $B$-module.

Saying that $A$ is an artin algebra means that $A$ is an algebra over some commutative ring $\Lambda$ so that $A$ is a finitely generated $\Lambda$-module, so it also has finite length as $\Lambda$-module. Since $M$ is finitely generated over $A$, it also has finite length as $\Lambda$-module. Now note that $B$ is an algebra over $\Lambda$ and so every $B$-submodule of $M$ is also a $\Lambda$-submodule.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!